# Are `AS`'s in `SELECT * FROM mytable AS t` and `CREATE VIEW AS (...)` the same command?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL,

```
SELECT * FROM mytable  AS t;

CREATE VIEW v AS (SELECT * FROM mytable);
```

In terms of syntax, are `AS`'s in the above two commands

- different clauses of `SELECT` command and of `CREATE VIEW` command respectively?
- or the same command themselves?

Thanks.

Comment: Why you are faced such a question?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM

> alias
>
> A substitute name for the FROM item containing the alias. An alias is
>   used for brevity or to eliminate ambiguity for self-joins (where the
>   same table is scanned multiple times). When an alias is provided, it
>   completely hides the actual name of the table or function; for example
>   given FROM foo AS f, the remainder of the SELECT must refer to this
>   FROM item as f not foo. If an alias is written, a column alias list
>   can also be written to provide substitute names for one or more
>   columns of the table.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html

> CREATE... VIEW...AS query

so they are different. same word, different usage - first defining alias name, second defining query...

Also `CREATE FUNCTION ... AS` for body definition and so on

Comment: Thanks. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530841/in-create-xxx-commands-when-is-as-or-of-used-and-when-not

Answer (score 2):

> different clauses of SELECT command and of CREATE VIEW command

Different yes, but it's not a "clause", it's a preposition.

> the same command

No. It's not a command, and even if it was it's not "the same".

"AS" (as used in SQL) is a *preposition* - a "connector word" that introduces the next part.

It is only used to make the SQL feel more English like, and when used before aliases (as in your first example) is optional.

Comment: Thanks. In English, "as" is a preposition. In SQL, is `AS` also called a preposition and Is `FROM ...` called a clause?

Comment: @Tim I've heard "from clause" and "where clause", but never "as clause". In both use cases you showed, it could be omitted. The first case because the language defines AS as optional when introducing an alias, and the second case because it's implied by the syntax - that is, the *only* term that can follow `CREATE VIEW view_name` is "AS", so it's redundant.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "redundant"?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530841/in-create-xxx-commands-when-is-as-or-of-used-and-when-not

Comment: @tim redundant means “adds no value”. In both cases if AS was left out, the parser could correctly parse the SQL.

Comment: Do you mean `as` in `create view viewname as (...)` can be omitted? In PostgreSQL, it can't.